# Setting of Environmental Variables which persist in Linux

Tags: linux, centos, environment-variables

I have added the following:

> export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/bin/

to my `/etc/profile` file. However when I run an install.sh script it keeps saying the environment variable is not set. I have also added similar lines to the bash_profile.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a shell script, it runs (by default) non-login and non-interactive--see [my answer to another question on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29811/11750) for a rundown of when and where bash looks for config files.  You will probably want to add the `-l` option to the shebang line to make it a login shell.

Comment: Your link was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a login before you can see the changes in `/etc/profile`. Try:

```
bash -l
```

for example.

Comment: Sorry.. I should have specified in the OP. I have tried re-logins and shut downs.